# multiple multicast on multiple interfaces

Tags: c++, linux, networking, multicast

OS: CentOS 5.5
Language: C++

I have done quite a bit of research on this but I can't find really any articles that's doing this exact setup I have. This is a pretty specific setup, so I am going to do my best to describe what I am doing and what I am trying to do.

I have a computer with 2 Ethernet ports (eth0 and eth1). Each one is receiving a different multicast broadcast at the same time. So 1 Multicast IP address and port is going to eth0 and another multicast IP address and port is going to eth1.

I am writing a program that is designed to listen to a given multicast IP address and port.

The goal is to be able to launch the program and listen to 1 of the multicast and at the same time launch a 2nd instance of the program that listens to the other multicast. The program itself is only designed to listen to 1 multicast at a time.

However I can not seem to have both programs running at the same time.

Using the "route" command I have been able to set up the routing table where I can receive 1 of the streams, but not the other. I can only ever get 1 stream going at a time, but not both.

eth0 is connected to: 10.10.20.50 -- multicast for this interface is 225.0.7.10 port 51007
eth1 is connected to: 192.168.20.21 -- multicast for this interface is 225.0.8.10 port 51008

If I do the route command, "route add default gw 10.10.20.50 eth0" I can receive the multicast on that address just fine

But as soon as I add "route add default gw 192.168.20.21 eth1" I can no longer receive the multicast on the 10.10.20.50 interface.

I do not get any errors with binding the sockets or setting the sockopts... the program just simply blocks on the recv call and never gets a message.

I have tried all sorts of combinations of the route command to support this, and I have done some various things in my connection code to fix this as well but with no luck. Here is my current connection code:

```
  //Create the UDP socket, check to make sure it was created successfully
  cout << "Initializing Connection..." << endl ;
  m_socket = socket ( AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP ) ;

  if( m_socket == -1 )
  {
    cout << "ERROR CREATING SOCKET: " << strerror(errno) << endl ;
    return false ;
  }

  cout << "Socket Created" << endl;

  //Setup socket binding information
  sockaddr_in addr ;
  bzero  ( ( char* ) &addr , sizeof ( addr ) ) ;
  addr . sin_family       = AF_INET ;
  addr . sin_addr.s_addr  = inet_addr(interface_addr) ; //10.10.20.50 or 192.168.20.21
  addr . sin_port         = htons ( port ) ;            //51007 or 51008

  //bind the socket, check for errors
  int result = bind ( m_socket , ( struct sockaddr* ) &addr , sizeof ( addr ) ) ;

  if ( result == -1 )
  {
    cout << "ERROR BINDING PORT: " << strerror ( errno ) << endl;
    shutdown ( m_socket , SHUT_RDWR ) ;
    return false ;
  }

  cout << "Socket Bound" << endl;

  //subscribe to the supplied IP address and port to listen on
  in_addr host_addr ;
  inet_pton ( AF_INET , ip_addrs . c_str () , & ( host_addr ) ) ;

  struct ip_mreq mreq;
  mreq . imr_multiaddr = host_addr ;       // multicast address 225.0.7.10 or 225.0.8.10
  mreq . imr_interface = addr . sin_addr ; //the 10.10.20.50 or 192.168.20.21 specified above

  result = setsockopt ( m_socket , IPPROTO_IP , IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq , sizeof(mreq) ) ;

  if ( result == -1 )
  {
    cout << "ERROR SETTING SOCKOPT SUBSCRIPTION: " << strerror(errno) << endl ;
    printSocketError();
    shutdown ( m_socket , SHUT_RDWR ) ;
    return false ;
  }

  /*
   * Read from the socket to get the initial bit of information we need so the
   * buffers can get allocated correctly, and the width and height of the application
   * can be defined.
   */
  cout << "Attempting to read from the socket..." << endl;
  MyPacket pckt ;
  recv ( m_socket , &pckt , sizeof ( pckt ) , MSG_PEEK ) ;

  cout << "Data Received... processing" << endl ;
```

I have also tried using the ip_mreqn struct to specify the interface manually and used the setsockopt for SOL_BINDTODEVICE setup (eth0 or eth1) but ran into the same problem as before where I could only get it to connect if I had a particular route setup... and even then only 1 would receive and not the other.

To reiterate... I need to have 2 copies of this program running at the same time.. each one listening to it's own specified multicast address coming from specific interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup two different routes, so different groups are routed to (and thus listened to on) given interface:

```
root:~# route add -net 225.0.7.10 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev eth0
root:~# route add -net 225.0.8.10 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev eth1
```

Then, while you program is running, you should be able to see what groups at listened to on what interface with `netstat -ng`.

#### Edit 0:

- The [`shutdown(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) call is for TCP only, does not make any sense for UDP.
- Check out the ["UNIX Network Programming, The Sockets Networking API"](http://www.unpbook.com/), Volume 1. It has a detailed chapter on how to do this properly. Code from the book is freely available.

#### Edit 1:

Get the source code for the UNP book I mentioned, its [here](http://www.unpbook.com/unpv13e.tar.gz). Look into `unpv13e/lib` directory in the unpacked archive, read the `mcast_join.c` file.

Comment: Nikolai, thanks for the response. I have actually tried doing those commands before but I get a "Netmask doesn't match route address" error when I execute them

Comment: Ok those commands executed successfully... Now my question is which address should I actually be binding to? INADDR_ANY? 10.10.20.51/192.168.20.21? Also.. how should I be doing my sockopt? do I need to worry about SOL_BINDTODEVICE as well as IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP?

Comment: Bind to the group address, don't bother with `BINDTODEVICE`.

Comment: Thanks for your input Nikolai, still having problems with it. I have tried these configurations in the c++ code with your route commands:
BIND: 192.168.20.21/10.10.20.50  port: 51008/51007
MREQ: interface 192.168.20.21/10.10.20.50 address: 225.0.8.10/225.0.7.10

I have also tried binding to the multicast addresses too, no success.

The program still hangs on recv. I noticed if I spam "ifconfig" that I can see the traffic size increase constantly while the program is running, and stop when the program is shut off

Answer (score 0):

Rather do this -
1. Create a Class.
2. Have a function which creates and binds IP and Port in that class.
3. Call that function twice from main function by using that class Object.

To verify the result you can use command netstat -g, which will show two instances corresponding to your Multicast IP.

I can code it if u want me to, but try to that by yourself first.